# Mailing_send_test error

Tags: civimail, error

I'm getting the following error when I'm trying to send a test email.

> Error in call to Mailing_send_test : Error in call to
>   MailingJob_create : DB Constraint Violation - possibly mailing_id
>   should possibly be marked as mandatory for this API. If so, please
>   raise a bug report

Civi was working yesterday. Some reports have been run since then but nothing else. I'm on 4.6.22 for Drupal.  Any thoughts on how I can fix this bug?

Comment: Check your civicrm error log. You will find more details there.

Answer (score 2):

I needed toL

> drush cc civicrm.

- clearing Civi cash via ui did not work
- drush cc all did not work

many thanks to Christia: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/19237