# Mail error when sending to smart groups

Tags: civimail, drupal, error

I haven't been working on the server or the website, but we are spontaneously getting the following error when sending a test mailing or scheduling a mailing:

When sending a test mailing:

> Error in call to Mailing_send_test : Error in call to
>   MailingJob_create : DB Error: unknown error

When scheduling a mailing:

> DB Error: unknown error

Here is the backtrace show with `drush ws`:

```
21021577  27/Jun 12:01  civicrm   debug     $backTrace = #0 /var/www/html/example/docroot/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(229):              
                                             CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)                                                                     
                                             #1 [internal function](): CRM_Core_Error::h                                                                      
 21021576  27/Jun 12:01  civicrm   debug     $Fatal Error Details = Array                                                                                     
                                             (                                                                                                                
                                                 [callback] => Array                                                                                          
                                                     (                                                                                                        
                                                         [0] => CRM_Core_Error                                                                                
                                                         [1] => handle                                                                                        
                                                     )                                                                                                        

                                                 [code] => -1                                                                                                 
                                                 [message] => DB Error: unknown                                                                               
 21021575  27/Jun 12:01  cron      notice    Cron run completed.                                                                                              
 21021574  27/Jun 12:01  civicrm   debug     $backTrace = #0 /var/www/html/example/docroot/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(229):              
                                             CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)                                                                     
                                             #1 [internal function](): CRM_Core_Error::h                                                                      
 21021573  27/Jun 12:01  civicrm   debug     $Fatal Error Details = Array                                                                                     
                                             (                                                                                                                
                                                 [callback] => Array                                                                                          
                                                     (                                                                                                        
                                                         [0] => CRM_Core_Error                                                                                
                                                         [1] => handle                                                                                        
                                                     )                                                                                                        

                                                 [code] => -1                                                                                                 
                                                 [message] => DB Error: unknown                                                                               
 21021572  27/Jun 12:01  civicrm   debug     $backTrace = #0 /var/www/html/example/docroot/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(229):              
                                             CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)                                                                     
                                             #1 [internal function](): CRM_Core_Error::h                                                                      
 21021571  27/Jun 12:01  civicrm   debug     $Fatal Error Details = Array                                                                                     
                                             (                                                                                                                
                                                 [callback] => Array                                                                                          
                                                     (                                                                                                        
                                                         [0] => CRM_Core_Error                                                                                
                                                         [1] => handle                                                                                        
                                                     )                                                                                                        

                                                 [code] => -1                                                                                                 
                                                 [message] => DB Error: unknown
```

Also noted:
Dashboard gives the following error:

> Unable to reach the server. Please refresh this page in your browser
>   and try again.

Using CiviCRM 4.7.15 and Drupal 7.50

What I've tried:

- tested outbound SMTP settings *passed*
- created a new mailing to test group only and scheduled it *passed*
- recreated mailing to go out to same smart groups *failed*
- `drush cc all` *didn't take care of the issue*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm embarassed to say, but though `drush cc all` (clear all caches) didn't work, once I ran `drush cc civicrm` the errors went away.

Comment: Should I just delete this question?

Comment: Your answer might still help others. We can also direct them to http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: Others like us. +1